# Linux audio control web alsamixer

Tags: linux, audio, web, alsa

Linux audio control are managed by a command line interface, it would be useful to access them from outside.

Would it be possible to access the control of alsamixer from a web app, like a django app?
Can please someone put me in the right direction of how to do this?

any advice is really appreciated

Comment: Mixer controls are implemented by the driver. You can access them with the same functions that `alsamixer` uses. (You still need to use C functions; executing `amixer` might be easier.)

Comment: finded what I need: http://pyalsaaudio.sourceforge.net/libalsaaudio.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Late reply, but I have not found anything like it, so I developed [ALSA Mixer WebUI](https://github.com/JiriSko/amixer-webui). Hopefully this is exactly what you're looking for.